# How to get MongoDB $map operator to return an array of values and not any array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

The following $map expression in MongoDB returns an array of objects with the key `createdAt`, which is a date value.

```
"$map": {
    "input": {
        // some expression here
    },
    as: "reputation",
    in: {
        "createdAt": "$$reputation.createdAt",
    },
}
```

For example the above query returns the following:

```
[{
   createdAt: "date1"
}, {
   createdAt: "date2"
}]
```

**How should I edit my  $map expression so that the $map expression returns an array of date values like so:**

```
[ "date1", "date2" ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did some more research and realised all you need to do is this:

```
"$map": {
    "input": {
        // some expression here
    },
    as: "reputation",
    in: "$$reputation.createdAt",
}
```